# Word For the Process of Finding Return on Investment

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics, technical, statistics

I am told that if I invest $20 in this Apple Stock, in one years time there is a:

- 10% chance I'll get back $25
- 10% chance I'll get back $20
- 30% chance I'll get back $15
- 50% chance I'll get back $10

So my what I'm calling my "Return on Investment" would be: $25 * .1 + $20 * .1 + $15 * .3 + $10 * .5 = $14

I'm assuming this is some sort of statistical calculation that I just did, but I'd like to know the name of this statistical process. (I would say something like amortization, but that's not right.)

Comment: You may call it "*average expected return*". http://www.zenwealth.com/businessfinanceonline/RR/ExpectedReturn.html

Comment: @Josh61 "Average expected return" is another word for "Return on Investment" I was hoping for the name of the process of calculating it.

Comment: "*The expected rate of return on a stock represents the mean of a probabilty distribution of possible future returns on the stock.*"  You should probably ask in the Finance or Math sites.

Comment: @Josh61 Possibly, I think you answered it right there though "Probability Distribution" perhaps?

Comment: Statisticians (well, [Jordan Ellenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_Ellenberg), who I'm currently reading) refer to the "expected **value**" of your $20 investment here as $14. That's to say, if you and 1000 friends each invest $20 you've put up $20,000, but most likely the total of all your stockholdings in a year's time will be fairly close to $14,000. So in non-specialist language we'd probably be talking about your (average) ***loss***, not "return".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sure, but what is the word for the process that they'd use to find the "expected value"? "Distribution of Probabilities"?

Comment: @Jonathan: If you mean the "process" of simply summing each possible outcome multiplied by its chance of occurring, I'm not sure there would be a word for applying such a trivial algebraic formula.

Comment: ...note that "expected value" doesn't exactly mean the amount you personally might expect to get back. As Ellenberg says, suppose you bet $10 on a dog that has a 10% chance of winning its race. If the dog wins you get $100; it it loses, you get nothing. The expected value there is $10 (10% of $100 + 90% of $0) - but you definitely *won't* end up with $10, because you're either going to get $100 or $0.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Quite. Just as there are 1.15 children in an average family.

Comment: @anemone Now you've done it. Kids are going to go home and ask their parents where fifteenths of babies come from.

Comment: The method is a fundamental technique in probability theory and has application in many fields beyond finance. When I studied this it was described as the summation of the value of the outcomes multiplied by their probabilities but I don't recall ever hearing a specific name for it.

Comment: The non-technical term that applies to your example is "counting your chickens before they are hatched."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "return" you describe is usually called [*expected value*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) (see also [*weighted average*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean)). For the process of determining it, I think no special term exists beyond the usual ones such as "calculating", "determining", "estimating", etc.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case, but thanks for the confirmation.